# Updating JTextArea Dynamically Without Threads

Tags: java, swing

One part of a uni assignment I have is to make a JTextArea in a pane, and have the text updated dynamically based on an Observer observing the class it gets its text from.

A snippet from the code I have:

```
// add the student info text area
Student s = lib.queryStudentList(uid);
LibraryObserver o = new LibraryObserver(s);

JTextArea infoArea = new JTextArea(o.getInfo());
```

The observer is implemented properly; it is notified whenever the student has changed its state, and changes its info as such.

However, the assignment calls for the textArea to be updated whenever the student's info changes, without closing and reopening the frame. We have not learned about threads or any of that, yet.

How would I do this without using threads? Or is it just a bad assignment? Or am I just being really dumb? (the latter, most likely)

Comment: You wouldn't create a new instance of the `JTextArea` to start with, but simply either call `setText` or `append` on the instance of the `JTextArea` you've added to the main screen

Comment: Care to elaborate? @madprogrammer

Comment: Create an instance of `JTextArea`, add it your screen.  When the observable changes for some reason, use this same instance of `JTextArea` and update it using either `setText` or `append`...